# Пунктуация в "условной" прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Помогите расставить знаки препинания в предложении:

> Она смотрела на Петра и ее взгляд говорил, типа ну и бревно же ты.

Как вы понимаете, здесь автор домысливает мысли или несказанные слова героя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве варианта:

**Она смотрела на Петра, и ее взгляд говорИл типа: "ну и бревно же ты".**

**Автор передает мысли персонажа**, но междометие "типа" относится скорее к авторской речи, что определенным образом характеризует его стиль. Двоеточием обозначена пауза в речи.

**Примеры (с разным оформлением):**

Вероятнее всего, мама впряглась за отца, типа **"ну и что что бил, так им и надо, я не против".**

Когда же приходит отчетливое понимание того, что контроль над ситуацией давно утрачен, а его мужское мнение никому не интересно, костромской мужчина срывается на реплику **типа «ну и дура!".**

И потом, когда "поздравьте друг друга" ― я к нему тянусь, а он так это на друзей смотрит, **типа "ну и где цветы?".**

Например, после реплики типа: **«Ну и жизнь у нас!"** [Марк Захаров. Суперпрофессия (1988-2000)]

Comment: Вы мне нравитесь, Арина. Как-то все с вами просто, да и мысли наши часто сходятся. Вы - либерал в русской грамматике и пунктуации, как и я.

Comment: Вы правы, мне не нравится, когда правила  воспринимаются только как жесткие инструкции. Наша система письма не такова, в определенных рамках она дает нам достаточно свободы для выражения своих мыслей. Мне кажется,что  современный протест  "неграмотной" молодежи против правил связан  именно с непониманием всех возможностей русского правописания. Правила не должны мешать людям свободно выражать свои мысли и эмоции,  и вот что интересно:  освоить такое письмо можно, даже находясь в большой дружбе с Розенталем.

Comment: Двоеточие после "типа" кажется мне странным. Его нет ни в одном из примеров, и ясно почему: слово "типа" говорит, что слова персонажа передаются не дословно (в кавычках стоит "типовая", приблизительная реплика).

Comment: Она смотрела на Петра, и ее взгляд  будто говорил:  "ну и бревно же ты". Это БСП.  Кроме того, в примерах есть прямая речь с двоеточием.

Comment: Ох уж этот современный сленг! :)) По-моему, так: *Eе взгляд говорил типа "ну и бревно же ты"* = *Eе взгляд говоил что-то вроде "ну и бревно же ты"*. Сравните: *Eе взгляд типа говорил: "ну и бревно же ты"* = *Eе взгляд будто говорил: "ну и бревно же ты"*